# What size pot to control the volume of a single small 4" 16 ohm speaker that's plugged into a headphone jack of my Soundblaster card in my PC?

Tags: potentiometer

I have a 4" 16 ohm speaker in the overhead of my flight simulator cockpit. It will be plugged into a headphone splitter that goes to my SoundBlaster board in my PC. I would like to use this speaker when I don't have the headphones on and it would be nice to be able to control the volume and maybe even turn it off completely when not in use. What would I need to do this? What size/type of potentiometer would I use?

Comment: your PC mixer can handle this

Comment: Which SoundBlaster model? Some have speaker output, some don't, and can't drive a speaker. Besides limiting volume by putting a potentiometer in series with a speaker level signal needs pretty high wattage potentiometer, so it would be better to just feed line level audio to an amplifier, and if amp has no volume control, then use a pot on line level audio.

Answer (score 0):

They make devices to control speaker volume downstream from the amp.They are referred to as Speaker L-Pad [(impedance) Ohm wattages are sometimes listed with it]. They can also be called Mono/Stereo Attenuator Audio Level Volume Control. Power levels upto about 100 watts are readily available and not to expensive.

Using this term: "speaker volume control" you will find many different units. I hope this solves your problem.